# In Razor, accept whole number without decimal

Tags: javascript, razor, html-helper

I'm facing an issue with a textbox to only allow whole numeric value, not  dot/decimal value in razor view. I looked around SO but unfortunately I can't find an answer.

JavaScript validation exists for *accept numeric value with dot*, but I want without dot/decimal.

cshtml:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(Employee => Employee.AlternateNumber, new { @id = "txtAlternateNumber", @class = "form-control", @type = "number" })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with razor, but rather html5, but adding `step` and `min` might help (depending on browser-support etc.):

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(Employee => Employee.AlternateNumber, new { @id = "txtAlternateNumber", @class = "form-control", @type = "number", @step="1", @min="0" })
```

A runnable example:

```html
<form>
<input type="number" step="1" min="0"> <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**For "realtime" checking, you have to use javascript:**

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(Employee => Employee.AlternateNumber, new { @id = "txtAlternateNumber", @class = "form-control", @type = "number", @step="1", @min="0", @onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" })
```

A runnable example:

```html
<form>
<input type="number" step="1" min="0" onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57"> <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me, when user try to type values in textbox it doesn't allow characters and dot value. Only accept numeric value at the time of keypress.

Comment: For the requirement "at time of keypress" you will have to use javascript.  I'll update with an example.

Answer (score 1):

if js validation is ok, you can do like:

```
$('form').on('keydown', '.digitfield', function (e) { -1 !== $.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13]) || (/65|67|86|88/.test(e.keyCode) && (e.ctrlKey === true || e.metaKey === true)) && (!0 === e.ctrlKey || !0 === e.metaKey) || 35 <= e.keyCode && 40 >= e.keyCode || (e.shiftKey || 48 > e.keyCode || 57 < e.keyCode) && (96 > e.keyCode || 105 < e.keyCode) && e.preventDefault() });
```

and then add the `digitfield` class to textbox

Comment: glad to help :)

Comment: this code worked on view page. but I want to put js function to other common js file in my project and call the function from view textbox onkey press event.

Comment: if you put the above code in a common js file, it will work in all views which include that js file